# Android Communication

Tags: android-wifi, wifi-direct

Let's say i have three android devices, Device A, B and C.
Now Device A wants to send a file to C but is too far away. Device A wants to use B to send a file to C.
What medium should be used for this idea and why?
1. Wifi
2. Wifi-Direct
3. Hotspot.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem is prettysame as is with the [Thaliproject](http://thaliproject.org/AndroidP2P).

So, first you would need to figure out

- how to discover devices,
- how to identify discovered devices, and also
- how to route the data to the identified destination.

I don't think there would be a simple answer on using XYZ for doing all the task, you would actually need to specify your requirements, and then see which technology/technologies would fit to solving the issues.

For example in [Thaili with first release](http://www.goland.org/story0/) the data delivery is handled via insecure-Bluetooth-sockets, while discovery & identification is handled via Wifi-Direct. Later versions will be likely using some other mixtures for tasks.